# Using Carbon in Laravel to show time differences

Tags: php, date, laravel-4, php-carbon

I'm a bit confused how to use this function. [Found this](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) and tried to follow but I've got some wired result. I've got date from array `Date A`

```
[time_utc] => 2016-10-11T19:21:34Z
```

Then I convert it using date function in php like this

```
$new_date = date('jS F Y \| h:i: A', strtotime($date));
```

and new date which I see on the page is `11/10/16 19:21pm`
Then I've pulled from my database `Date B` which is in `timestamp` type and looks like `2016-10-11 19:19:15` and perform same converting

```
created_at->format('d/m/y G:ia')
```

which result in same format `11/10/16 19:19pm`
Now with carbon I'm trying to see difference from today's date:

```
<pre>{{ created_at->format('d/m/y G:ia')}} | {{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($order->created_at))->diffForHumans() }}</pre>
<pre>{{ $new_date ?: "Null" }} | {{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($new_date))->diffForHumans() }}</pre>
```

But result is:

```
11/10/16 19:19pm | 2 days ago
11/10/16 19:21pm | 46 years ago
```

Why second date which come from array show **46 years ago**?

Comment: Is it possible to convert it somehow because I can't control it since it comes from api cal?

Comment: ignore me, I missed the `strtotime` part

Comment: Ah, i see. If I don't put new format `'d/m/y G:ia'` it is working correctly.

Comment: It occurs to me that `19:21pm` does not make any sense. Could you have a `19:21am` as well?

Comment: Well ... nope :)  removed it and now on second date which was 46 years ago I've got `11/10/16 19:21 | 3 weeks from now` which is close to reality but still not correct :)

Comment: That issue is because in PHP `11/10/16` is interpreted as a US date which means `Nov 10 2016`. European dates should be `11-10-16` or you can manually specify the format.

Comment: so for PHP `11` is the day but for `Carbon` is the year? Because I've changed it to `'d-m-y G:i'` and got `11-10-16 19:21 | 4 years ago`

Comment: Ive make them `Y/m/d G:i` And now it's okay `2016/10/11 19:21 | 2 days ago`

Comment: Check http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php